# Google App Engine Data store vs. Firebase Database

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-compute-engine, objectify

I'd like to ask for the pros and cons between choosing either Firebase or Objectify (convenience interface for Google's Data store), as storage for the backend.

I'd like to make it as general an answer as possible, but in my use case, we have a Java desktop application, that will communicate with JSPs and servlets on Google App Engine, as well as Docker instances served on Google Container/Compute Engine (GCE/GKE). We have already implemented Firebase for authentication.

Our data scheme is simple, for now. No complex class, nothing inner, nested, or what not. The bulk of what we want to store are JSON objects, as flat in nature, as possible.

We're debating whether to store in Firebase as is (JSON), or to create a POJO server-side, to store in Objectify. We've done both, and we've researched the performance and scalability of these 2 services, as well as we can.

We deem both to be adequate for our needs, but expert opinion is always desirable, especially when considering long-term growth, inter-service convenience (e.g. GAE to GCE and back) and costs. Any other sort of input, is welcome too, of course.

Comment: are you talking about the free version or do you pay for Firebase Services and/or Google App Engine?

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Michael. We're putting together an MVP, so we're currently using the free versions of everything. Of course, this will change once it scales, which is why we want to ask this question now, before things get real in production.